# Hibernate in JBoss drools

Tags: hibernate, jboss

Rule is showing the following error when using with hibernate

> [22,22]: [ERR 102] Line 22:22 mismatched input 'FROM' expecting '(' in
>   rule "Name" in pattern Contact

I am inserting:

```
static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
static{
    sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
}
session =sessionFactory.openSession();
ksession.setGlobal("hibernateSession", session);
```

Once I add drools to the knowledge builder before inserting rules

```
package drools
//list any import classes here.
import droolsexec.Contact;
//declare any global variables here
global org.hibernate.Session hibernateSession;
rule "Name"
dialect "java" 
when
// message: Message( status =="GOODBYE" )
contact: Contact from hibernateSession.createQuery("from Contact").list();
then
System.out.println( contact.getFirstName()); 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the parentheses are required in the `Contact`, as:

```
when
    contact: Contact() from ...
then
    ...
```